# How to assign color to error bars? [Matplotlib]

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, errorbar

I am new at Matplotlib and could not find a way to assign colors to error bars...in my data (attached) the mean values are 'numbers' and the SD ('error') is in the column 'sd'. I grouped data by 'strain' (4 categories; mc, mut1, etc.). Colors are 'strains' (lines) but error colors don't match.

I want them to be the same as line color (from color vector "c"). Thanks!

The file is https://anonfiles.com/d8A7m4F5o0/mutdp_csv

```
muts = pd.read_csv('mutdp.csv')
#SUBSET
# Select rows (i.e. 1 to 28)
gr=muts[1:28]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9.9))

c=['b','y','r','g']

#Data GR ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
grstrain=gr.groupby(['time','strain']).mean()['numbers'].unstack()
grstrain.plot.line(ax=ax, style=['-o','-o','-o','-o'],color=c, ls = '--', linewidth=2.7)

# Error
ax.errorbar(gr.time, gr.numbers, yerr=gr.sd, ls='')

#(SCALE)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(0.04, 3)

# Label
ax.set_xlabel('Time (hours)' )
ax.set_ylabel('Growth (OD)')
ax2.set_ylabel('ylabel2')

#SAVE FIG!

plt.show()
```

Comment: try `ax.errorbar(gr.time, gr.numbers, yerr=gr.sd, ls='', color=[i for i in c for _i in range(7)])` ?

Comment: it worked Ramon! thank you very much! :) what's the rationale behind it? (did not know a "for" cycle could be used this way; and would love to learn! )

Comment: `color` is a keyword argument for `errorbar` (actually, for any `line`object, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_color)). Then, the tricky part is that `errorbar` sets `color` for each point, not for each series, so just saying `color=c` won't do it. I put together a hacky _nested list comprehension_ (that's the name of `for` loops used this way) because I knew how many points were there. May be a color series would be a better approach.

Comment: so much clearer now! thank you! indeed I tried "color=c" and it resulted in different colors for every point along X axis. 
Now I wanted to add the "capsize=3", but it throws an error (ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument). I found this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490293/why-do-i-get-an-invalid-rgba-argument-valueerror-when-defining-capsize-to-my-e) where "error_kw" sorted the issue for bars... any suggestion for placing caps (ie. capsize=3) having the same color as error bars? thanks again!